# How to disable Appflow Live Updates in IONIC app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-appflow

I have Ionic Appflow **Live Updates** configured and deploying correctly (in a Capacitor project). The problem is that when I deploy manually the app to my phone in order to do some development tests, it logically keeps updating to the latest Appflow deployment. I'd like to disable Live Updates temporarily, in order to be able to test a new version in my phone, without being it updated. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to configure your app to disable updates: in `capacitor.config.json` file add the following to the `cordova.preferences` object:

```
{
  ...

  },
  "cordova": {
    "preferences": {
      "DisableDeploy": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

This should stop auto updating your test app. Remember to revert it to false before commiting the project for Appflow deployment.

Read the [Documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova/migrating-from-cordova-to-capacitor?__hstc=57877749.e53672e756a0728f0b0c691e20c153ad.1651589722464.1651674039707.1651684124335.5&__hssc=57877749.1.1651684124335&__hsfp=2112455890#cordova-plugin-preferences).